# EF Core do I need include when I am selecting specific columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have this query

```
var upcomingThreats = context.Threats
                        .Include(t => t.DateRange)
                        .Include(t => t.TimeRange)
                        .Include(t => t.ThreatNotification)
                            .ThenInclude(n => n.ThreatNotificationToUser)
                                .ThenInclude(u => u.User)
                        .Where(t => t.ThreatNotification != null && t.ThreatNotification.ThreatNotificationToUser != null && t.ThreatNotification.ThreatNotificationToUser.Count > 0 && t.ThreatNotification.NotificationType == NotificationType.Email)
                        .Where(t => t.DateRange.Any(d => today > d.ActionDate))
                        .AsNoTracking().ToList();
```

I am working on some performance where I am thinking of selecting just those columns that I need further in my code. So I came up with this

```
var upcomingThreats = context.Threats
                        .Include(t => t.DateRange)
                        .Include(t => t.TimeRange)
                        .Include(t => t.ThreatNotification)
                            .ThenInclude(n => n.ThreatNotificationToUser)
                                .ThenInclude(u => u.User)
                        .Where(t => t.ThreatNotification != null && t.ThreatNotification.ThreatNotificationToUser != null && t.ThreatNotification.ThreatNotificationToUser.Count > 0 && t.ThreatNotification.NotificationType == NotificationType.Email)
                        .Where(t => t.DateRange.Any(d => today > d.ActionDate))
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .Select(threat => new ThreatApiServiceModel
                        {
                            DateRange = threat.DateRange,
                            TimeRange = threat.TimeRange,
                            RiskAssessmentId = threat.RiskAssessmentId,
                            Id = threat.Id,
                            OtherName = threat.OtherName,
                            Users = threat.ThreatNotification.ThreatNotificationToUser.Select(usr => new SimpleUserWithOrganizationId
                            {
                                OrganizationId = usr.User.OrganizationId,
                                UserId = usr.UserId,
                                Email = usr.User.Email,
                                Name = usr.User.Name,
                            }).ToList(),
                            NotificationType = threat.ThreatNotification.NotificationType
                        })
                        .ToList();
```

My question is that in the second query do I need to include the navigation properties as I have condition on them or not? Can I just do this?

```
var upcomingThreats = context.Threats
                        .Where(t => t.ThreatNotification != null && t.ThreatNotification.ThreatNotificationToUser != null && t.ThreatNotification.ThreatNotificationToUser.Count > 0 && t.ThreatNotification.NotificationType == NotificationType.Email)
                        .Where(t => t.DateRange.Any(d => today > d.ActionDate))
                        .AsNoTracking()
                        .Select(threat => new ThreatApiServiceModel
                        {
                            DateRange = threat.DateRange,
                            TimeRange = threat.TimeRange,
                            RiskAssessmentId = threat.RiskAssessmentId,
                            Id = threat.Id,
                            OtherName = threat.OtherName,
                            Users = threat.ThreatNotification.ThreatNotificationToUser.Select(usr => new SimpleUserWithOrganizationId
                            {
                                OrganizationId = usr.User.OrganizationId,
                                UserId = usr.UserId,
                                Email = usr.User.Email,
                                Name = usr.User.Name,
                            }).ToList(),
                            NotificationType = threat.ThreatNotification.NotificationType
                        })
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Any reason you didn't just simply run your code and see if it works?

Comment: I ran and it worked but I wanted to understand why it works as my understanding was to use include even if they are just being used in where clause.

Comment: You do not need `Include` if you use `Select`. And there is no documentation that claims that `Include` should be put everywhere. It is needed only for loading related entities if you select WHOLE entity, otherwise it is just ignored.

Comment: `AsNoTracking()` is not needed if you select custom entity via `Select`. EF Core do not track custom projected entities. It tracks only WHOLE entities.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I would argue that in this case the related entities are being used as a source when constructing an entity inside `Select` (e.g. `TimeRange = threat.TimeRange`), so `Include` is still needed for this case. Could you please clarify why it's not needed?

Comment: @SergeyKudriavtsev, no it is not needed. But if you need to load TimeRange with another  navigation properties, yes Includes are needed.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't have to use `Include()` eager loading for where condition on a navigation property.

The `Where(predicate)` and the `Select(selector)` will be translated to SQL.
To monitor you translated SQLs you can enable EFCore Logging by adding this code to the Database Context.

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
=> optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
```