EF Core .Include and .AsNoTracking correct usage
There were so many posts from a few years ago that state you need to specify .AsNoTracking once before you materialize the query; then someone says its wrong and you have to do once at the top, which would make it valid for the entire query. However, these posts were really old and probably irrelevant to EF6 and above.
Consider the following complex query scenario involving multiple entities and includes (I removed part of the WHERE clause and also the projection just to minimize the size of the query):
var dataSet1 = _dbContext.MarketTransactions.AsNoTracking()
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .Include(a => a.Commodity).ThenInclude(a => a.Product).AsNoTracking()
    .Include(a => a.Contract).ThenInclude(a => a.Customer).AsNoTracking()
    .Include(a => a.Offer).ThenInclude(a => a.Customer).AsNoTracking()
    .Where(f => f.IsActive && (f.Source == EMarketTransactionSource...))
    .GroupJoin(
        _dbContext.HedgeAccounts.AsNoTracking(), 
        transaction => transaction.MarketAccount,
        hedgeAcct => hedgeAcct.Account, 
        (transaction, hedgeAcct) => new { Transaction = transaction, HedgeAccounts = hedgeAcct }) 
    .SelectMany(
        x => x.HedgeAccounts.DefaultIfEmpty(), 
        (x, hedgeAcct) => new { x.Transaction, HedgeAccount = hedgeAcct })
    .Select(f => new ...);

var dataSet2 = _dbContext.Set<OfferMonitoring>().AsNoTracking()
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .Include(a => a.Offer).ThenInclude(a => a.Commodity).ThenInclude(a => a.Product).AsNoTracking()
    .Include(a => a.Offer).ThenInclude(a => a.Customer).AsNoTracking()
    .Where(f => f.Action.Value == EOfferMonitorAction....)
    .Select(f => new ...);

var query = dataSet1.Union(dataSet2);

var total = await query.CountAsync(cancellationToken);

query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.UpdatedOn ?? x.CreationDate);
query = query.GetPagedQuery(request.Filter.Start, request.Filter.Limit);
var items = await query.ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

In this scenario:

Should .AsNoTracking() be applied globally once at the beginning of the query (_dbContext.MarketTransactions.AsNoTracking() and _dbContext.Set<OfferMonitoring>().AsNoTracking()), or should it be applied before each include or join clause?
What are the performance implications of each approach, especially considering the potential size of the result set?
Are there any differences in behavior or performance between Entity Framework Core versions that should be considered?


I guess the only way to know the performance implications would be to test. I have a hard time imagining AsNoTracking would be needed on every include

I'm not an EF expert, but everything I have read suggest that AsNoTracking applies to the whole query. So once should be enough. Putting it at the start of the query might help readability, but should not be required.

Have you tried to update anything on this query? I would assume nothing is tracked when you finish query with .Select(f => new ...);.

It's well documented what AsNoTracking does.


Should .AsNoTracking() be applied globally once at the beginning of the query and or should it be applied before each include or join clause?

AsNoTracking sets the tracking behavior for the whole query, subsequent calls will have no effect, so use a single call (personally I prefer to add it at the start of the query due to better readability)

What are the performance implications of each approach, especially considering the potential size of the result set?

As rule of thumb AsNoTracking should result in better performance in read-only scenarios but you should always benchmark it yourself if for some reason EF Core mapping/query processing becomes bottleneck (which quite rarely does, usually performance problems lie in query translation and/or database)
I highly recommend to read the Tracking vs. No-Tracking Queries section of the docs and the Efficient Querying one which gives the following comparison for the tracking vs not tracking queries:

Here are the results for a benchmark comparing tracking vs. no-tracking behavior for a query loading 10 Blogs with 20 Posts each. The source code is available here, feel free to use it as a basis for your own measurements.




Method
NumBlogs
NumPostsPerBlog
Mean
Error
StdDev
Median
Ratio
RatioSD
Gen 0
Gen 1
Gen 2
Allocated




AsTracking
10
20
1,414.7 us
27.20 us
45.44 us
1,405.5 us
1.00
0.00
60.5469
13.6719
-
380.11 KB


AsNoTracking
10
20
993.3 us
24.04 us
65.40 us
966.2 us
0.71
0.05
37.1094
6.8359
-
232.89 KB



Again - if this part of the performance is a concern - benchmark your actual scenario (including the actual data distribution), also there is one more option worth considering - AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution which in theory can give some performance benefits but I was not able to find such scenario in my case.

Thank you about the detailed response! In that case, I should get rid of all .AsNoTracking occurrences apart from the one at the top, but does that include .GroupJoin(_dbContext.HedgeAccounts.AsNoTracking()? Should it also be done in both parts of the Union?

@nop GroupJoin results in a single EF Core query (do not confuse with actual SQL query) so it should not be needed.

@nop why is GroupJon used in the first place? EF will generate JOINs based on the relations between the entities. One could question the need for Include too - EF will include related entities as needed if they're used in the Select clause. Finally, var query = dataSet1.Union(dataSet2); is a smell - those are queries, not datasets. This will result in a big slow query. The performance impact will be far worse than entity tracking.

@nop the way the code is written, it counts stuff it doesn't have to. There's no reason to include related entities or Select to find out how many MarketTransactions or OfferMonitoring results there are. The database can't simply the query though, because it's asked to count the result of the final Select, so it's forced to perform those JOINs

@nop also note that using custom projection (Select) results in Include's being ignored AFAIK.

@Panagiotis Kanavos, GroupJoin is used because I'm unable to create a relationship on that one. They've used Guid.Empty for some records as opposed to null

This has nothing to do with relations. Relations aren't foreign key constraints. In any case, the COUNT query you try to execute is a lot more expensive than what you really need

@PanagiotisKanavos, https://pastebin.com/8mKSQjP7 this is the whole query. You're right, the count shouldn't need to include all those joins

@PanagiotisKanavos, https://pastebin.com/ziXKeZfX, I don't think we can get rid of the .Union since there are lots of filters, can we?

@GUruStron, I think you're right. Select and Where doesn't require eager loading via Include: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75218582/ef-core-do-i-need-include-when-i-am-selecting-specific-columns

As far as I remember, in Entity Framework Core, applying .AsNoTracking() at the start of a query is sufficient to affect the entire query, making all entities returned by that query not tracked by the DbContext. This means for your complex query, applying .AsNoTracking() once at the beginning (_dbContext.MarketTransactions.AsNoTracking() and _dbContext.Set().AsNoTracking()) is the correct and efficient approach. There's no need to apply it before each include or join clause; doing so is redundant.
Nonetheless, I think it is still worth making some performance tests, just to observe the outcome.
